# Print position of recurring words in List

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to find position of words in a sentence. But if there are recurring words in the sentence it will print the position of where the word first occurred. For example I want the program to do something like this:

```
sentence = 'Ask Not What Your Country Can Do For You Ask What You Can Do For Your Country'

recurringword = ['Ask', 'Not', 'What', 'Your', 'Country', 'Can', 'Do', 'For', 'You']

pos = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 2, 8, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4]
```

My Code:

```
sentence = 'Ask Not What Your Country Can Do For You Ask What You Can Do For Your Country'

print sentence
words_into_list = sentence.split(" ")

recurring_word = 'Ask'

word = ""
word_list=[]


for i in range(len(words_into_list)):
if words_into_list[i] in word_list:

    print "Not A Unique Word"
else:
    word_list.append(words_into_list[i])
print word_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each word in the sentence, finding the position of the first occurence of that word:

```
sentence = 'Ask Not What Your Country Can Do For You Ask What You Can Do For Your Country'

words = sentence.split(" ")

[(i for i,v in enumerate(words) if (v == word)).next() for word in words]
# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 2, 8, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4]
```

### quick explanation:

The outer loop is a for comprehension that iterates through each word in the list:

```
[... for word in words]
```

The inner loop extracts the indexes words in the list which match a given string, then grabs the index of the first occurence using `next`.

```
(i for i,v in enumerate(words) if (v == word)).next()
```

When we put them together we get nested loop that iterates through each word in  the list, and for each word, extracts the position of its first occurrence.

Also, it's not necessary to find recurring words to solve this problem, but if it's necessary otherwise:

```
recurring_words = set([word for word in words if words.count(word) > 1])
```